# How to fix error in the "make" step for a Simple Image Publisher (C )?

Tags: image, ros, publisher

**I am working on ROS groovy, and I want to write a Simple Image Publisher (C++) as described in http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages. When I want to make the package, I face an error as follows. 
How can I fix the problem?**

...
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/my_publisher.dir/src/my_publisher.cpp.o
/home/fatima/learning_image_transport/src/my_publisher.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/fatima/learning_image_transport/src/my_publisher.cpp:17:44: error: ‘sensor_msgs::CvBridge’ has not been declared
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_publisher.dir/src/my_publisher.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/fatima/learning_image_transport/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_publisher.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/fatima/learning_image_transport/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fatima/learning_image_transport/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2

**Thanks,
Samira**

Comment: Can you show CMakeLists.txt and packages.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the following dependencies? sensor_msgs, cv_bridge, std_msgs, image_transport to your package?

I believe the example is out dated. I assume you included `<cv_bridge/CvBridge.h>` but the file in *groovy* should be found at `<cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>`.

Apart from that, IplImage is part of an old version of OpenCV which was written in C. The newer versions support C++ where you can use cv::Mat as an image. cv::Mat is easier to handle.

Checkout this tutorial [CvBridge using cv::Mat](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages). It shows how to convert ros images to opencv images and vice versa. The cv::Mat is contained in the cv_bridge::CvImage wrapper class.